# How to declare a function pointer (function that we don't know the arguments) as a class member?

Tags: c++, templates, button, pointer-to-member

I'm trying to implement a button function, and I thought about using some function pointers to say to the program what function must it calls if the button is pressed.

The thing is that the functions the program is going to call have various arguments and various number of arguments (but the functions always return void), and of course I don't know how to declare my function pointer.

How can I implement that ? 
Should I use some templates ?
Can I do something like an array of type with templates, or is this non-sense ?

This is what my actual button class looks like :

```
#ifndef BUTTON_H_INCLUDED
#define BUTTON_H_INCLUDED

#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

#include <string>

class Button {
typedef unsigned short int usi_t;
public:
    Button();

    void updateState() {
        (isHover()) ? {
            m_currentBackgroundColor = m_backgroundColorIfHover;
            m_currentTextColor = m_textColorIfHover;
        } : {
            m_currentBackgroundColor = m_backgroundColorIfNothing;
            m_currentTextColor = m_textColorIfNothing;
        }
    }

private:
    /* State of the button */
    bool isHover() const {
        if (sf::Mouse.getPosition().x >= m_x && sf::Mouse.getPosition().x < m_x + m_w &&
            sf::Mouse.getPosition().x >= m_y && sf::Mouse.getPosition().y < m_y + m_h) {
                return true;
            }
        return false;
    }
    bool isClicked() const {
        if (isHover() && sf::Mouse.isButtonPressed(Left))
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    /* Function the button calls */
    void(*m_functionPtr)(/* What should I put here ? Should I use templates before the beginning of my class ? */);

    /* Position of the button */
    usi_t m_x;
    usi_t m_y;

    /* Dimension of the button */
    usi_t m_w; //weight
    usi_t m_h; //height

    /* Background color of the button */
    sf::Color m_currentBackgroundColor;
    sf::Color m_backgroundColorIfNothing;
    sf::Color m_backgroundColorIfHover;

    /* Text color of the button */
    sf::Color m_currentTextColor;
    sf::Color m_textColorIfNothing;
    sf::Color m_textColorIfHover;

    /* Border thickness and color */
    sf::Color m_borderColor;
    usi_t m_borderThickness;
    usi_t m_borderShadowThickness;

    /* Text of the button */
    std::string m_text;
};

#endif // BUTTON_H_INCLUDED
```

PS: In fact, I realized while eating that my question doesn't make any sense in my context. I'm not going to delete this question, supposing it will help somebody. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Do you want the function pointer type to change at runtime or will it be static for any given button?

Comment: You may consider using a `std::function ` member variable, rather than a raw function pointer.

Comment: Make a proper test case showing relevant  code only - especially how the information should flow (For that you need no button, etc ...)

Comment: If your functions have various numbers of arguments - how are you going to _call_ them?

Comment: @Useless. As the button is the invoker, it shall have the prerogative of determining the amount of arguments that the function shall have.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I implement that ? Should I use some templates ? Can I do
>   something like an array of type with templates, or is this non-sense ?

If you are using c++11, std::function would work well as member functions (and any type T that has overloaded operator() can bind to it).

You could then for the sake of your client ease the binding of e.g member functions by using function templates:

Also note that a lambda automatically binds to std::function (as with any other functor). See example below (using bind or lambda):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

struct Button
{
    const std::string name_;
    std::function<void(const Button&)> function_;

    Button(std::string&& name)
    : name_(name)
    {
    }

    template <class Receiver>
    void setOnButtonClick_lambda(
      Receiver& receiver, void (Receiver::*memberfunction)(const Button&) )
    {
      auto* pReciever = &receiver; // can be done inside [] in C++14
      // create a lambda, store it in the std::function:
      function_ = [pReciever,memberfunction](const Button& b){
        (pReciever->*memberfunction)(b);
      };
    }

    template <class Receiver>
    void setOnButtonClick_bind(
      Receiver& receiver, void (Receiver::*memberfunction)(const Button&) )
    {
      function_ = std::bind(memberfunction, receiver, std::placeholders::_1);
    }

    void click()
    {
        (function_)(*this);
    }

};
struct Receiver
{
    void call(const Button& b){ std::cout << "Hallo from " << b.name_ << std::endl; }   
};

int main() 
{
    Receiver r;
    Button b1("b1 - bind");
    Button b2("b2 - lambda");

    b1.setOnButtonClick_bind(r, &Receiver::call);
    b2.setOnButtonClick_lambda(r, &Receiver::call);
    b1.click();
    b2.click();
    return 0;
}
```

or if you don't have the luxury of c++11, you can use the command pattern  (the example below builds):

```
#include <iostream>

struct Cmd 
{
    virtual void execute() = 0;   
    virtual ~Cmd(){} 
};

struct Button
{
  private: 
    Cmd* onClick_;

    Button& operator=(Button);
    Button(const Button&);

  public:
      Button(): onClick_(){}
      ~Button()
      {
        delete onClick_;
      }

      void setOnClick(Cmd* onClick)
      {
        onClick_ = onClick;
      }

      void press()
      {
        if (onClick_){ onClick_->execute(); }
      }
};


 template <class Receiver> 
 struct Function : public Cmd
 {   
   typedef void(Receiver::*Callback)();

   Receiver& receiver_;   
   Callback call_;

   Function (Receiver& receiver, Callback call)   :
     receiver_(receiver),
     call_(call)   
   {   }   
   virtual void execute()   
   {
     (receiver_.*call_)(); 
   }
  };


struct Receiver
{
  Receiver()
  : btn_()
  {
    btn_.setOnClick(new Function<Receiver>(*this, &Receiver::call));
  }

  void testButtonPress()
  {
    btn_.press();
  }

  void call()
  {
    std::cout << "Pressed..." << std::endl;
  }

  Button btn_;  
};

int main() 
{
    Receiver receiver;
    receiver.testButtonPress();
    return 0;
}
```

The idea is then that you receive Cmd as base to your button, and execute the command, causing the real function to be called without needing to know the type.

... or use a library like boost, that provides an implementation of std::function ([see BoostLibs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/function.html))

Comment: Feel free to revert the lambda change.  You said you hadn't confirmed the syntax, so I thought I'd drop in syntax that I'm certain works.  (also removed your salutations, as advised by http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts stack overflow consensus)

Comment: Syntax now confirmed. "Feel free to revert the lambda change?". Not sure what you mean. OK... thanks. The lambda change is a good alternative.

Comment: I just find `bind` to be overly esoteric, when we now have lambda: plus, `bind` has strange corner cases.